# Can someone explain how a kernel trick makes things computationally easier?

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

This author states that when we use the kernel trick, we map original features to the distance between two values.  I have two questions regarding this:

1. I'm not seeing how this is computationally faster.  What exactly goes on that makes this faster?
2. I'm not seeing how knowing the distance between two points allows us to classify values?  Don't we need to know which direction a point is in relation to another point so that we can insert our hyperplane?

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1. you are not making the projection and calculating distances, you are directly calculating distances. By not projecting you are saving computations

Comment: 2. You are training a classifier, which means that you already know a class and want to learn a function f(x) which best separates the classes. Knowing the distance does nothing to classify values unless you have the function. Once you have function (which is the hyperplane) you can see where a given point falls with respect to the hyperplane.

Comment: Take a look at Andrew Ng's notes: (http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf). Hope it helps.